# Phonegap Camera Plugin Lock Orientation

Tags: cordova, camera, uiwebview, phonegap-plugins

Phonegap camera plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera not respecting the orientation set on the config.xml file. My app is lock in landscape, when camera opens it respect the config and it sets landscape, but when rotating the device(while the camera is open) the camera rotates to portrait. I want to prevent this from happening.

I wouldn't question this if only the rotation bug on webview(where the webview gets cut off) is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are the person that reported this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11887.

I also have struggled with this issue, but supposedly there is a fix in the latest version of cordova-plugin-camera. I haven't figured out how to actually use it (as the usage is still undocumented), but here's the link to the PR that added the functionality: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/167.

If anyone figures out the best way to use this new feature, please comment here or add a better answer.